# SQL: difference between PARTITION BY and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I've been using `GROUP BY` for all types of *aggregate* queries over the years.  Recently, I've been reverse-engineering some code that uses `PARTITION BY` to perform aggregations.

In reading through all the documentation I can find about `PARTITION BY`, it sounds a lot like `GROUP BY`, maybe with a little extra functionality added in.

Are they two versions of the same general functionality or are they something different entirely?

Answer (score 539, accepted):

They're used in different places. `GROUP BY` modifies the entire query, like:

```
select customerId, count(*) as orderCount
from Orders
group by customerId
```

But `PARTITION BY` just works on a [*window function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)), like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#ROW_NUMBER()_window_function):

```
select row_number() over (partition by customerId order by orderId)
    as OrderNumberForThisCustomer
from Orders
```

- `GROUP BY` normally reduces the number of rows returned by rolling
  them up and calculating averages or sums for each row.
- `PARTITION BY` does not affect the number of rows returned, but it
  changes how a window function's result is calculated.

Comment: nice answer, would you please write a sample of a returned results for each of them?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani you can run both queries against Northwind, which may or may not be installed by default depending on your sql server version. If not you can search for it on s downloads page.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Arunprasanth's answer below shows returned results which can save you time as opposed to jumping through more learning hoops and time to learn Northwind

Comment: More on windows functions (in SQL): http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/

Comment: https://itcodehub.blogspot.com/2019/03/difference-between-group-by-and.html - more info and example about differences between group by and partition by in sql

Comment: We could use this function well for answering this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153387/fetching-values-from-a-table-without-using-cursors

Answer (score 334):

We can take a simple example.

Consider a table named `TableA` with the following values:

```
id  firstname                   lastname                    Mark
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   arun                        prasanth                    40
2   ann                         antony                      45
3   sruthy                      abc                         41
6   new                         abc                         47
1   arun                        prasanth                    45
1   arun                        prasanth                    49
2   ann                         antony                      49
```

**`GROUP BY`**

> The SQL GROUP BY clause can be used in a SELECT statement to collect
>   data across multiple records and group the results by one or more
>   columns.
>
> In more simple words  GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with
>   the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more
>   columns.

Syntax:

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n, 
       aggregate_function (aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
GROUP BY expression1, expression2, ... expression_n;
```

We can apply `GROUP BY` in our table:

```
select SUM(Mark)marksum,firstname from TableA
group by id,firstName
```

Results:

```
marksum  firstname
----------------
94      ann                      
134     arun                     
47      new                      
41      sruthy
```

In our real table we have 7 rows and when we apply `GROUP BY id`, the server group the results based on `id`:

In simple words:

> here `GROUP BY` normally reduces the number of rows returned by rolling
>   them up and calculating `Sum()` for each row.

**`PARTITION BY`**

Before going to PARTITION BY, let us look at the `OVER` clause:

**According to the MSDN definition:**

> OVER clause defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a
>   query result set. A window function then computes a value for each row
>   in the window. You can use the OVER clause with functions to compute
>   aggregated values such as moving averages, cumulative aggregates,
>   running totals, or a top N per group results.

*PARTITION BY will not reduce the number of rows returned.*

We can apply PARTITION BY in our example table:

```
SELECT SUM(Mark) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS marksum, firstname FROM TableA
```

Result:

```
marksum firstname 
-------------------
134     arun                     
134     arun                     
134     arun                     
94      ann                      
94      ann                      
41      sruthy                   
47      new
```

Look at the results - it will partition the rows and returns *all* rows, unlike GROUP BY.

Comment: `partition by` *can* affect the number of rows, it just won't *reduce* the number of rows.

Comment: What would be the difference if i were to change the `SELECT` into  `SELECT DISTINCT` to the second query? wouldn't that return the same data-set as the `GROUP BY` query? What are the reasons of choosing one or the other?

Comment: @Erick3E please have a look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375074/distinct-with-partition-by-vs-groupby

Comment: I like this answer better because it shows how the Aggregate functions Min/Max/Sum etc work on Partitions.  The Row_Number() example doesn't make it as clear.  Normally I use an aggregate function with GROUP BY but just noticed that PARTITION-OVER has the same methods and wondered the same thing the OP did - which lead me here. Thanks!

Comment: @ripvlan I agree. This answer clarifies that doing something like SELECT column1,AVG(column2) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) returns all the rows and the average of column 2 that is calculated with respect to column 1.

Comment: Another way to think of it is: A partitioned query can be useful when we want each row to have both the unique values and aggregate values. Or when we want to compute unique values based on aggregate values. For example, we might want to compare the price of a given order to the average price of an order.

Answer (score 61):

`partition by` doesn't actually roll up the data.  It allows you to reset something on a per group basis.  For example, you can get an ordinal column within a group by partitioning on the grouping field and using `rownum()` over the rows within that group.  This gives you something that behaves a bit like an identity column that resets at the beginning of each group.

Answer (score 46):

> PARTITION BY 
>   Divides the result set into partitions. The window function is applied to each partition separately and computation restarts for each partition.

Found at this link: [OVER Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Answer (score 42):

`PARTITION BY` is analytic, while `GROUP BY` is aggregate.  In order to use `PARTITION BY`, you have to contain it with an [OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Comment: `PARTITION BY is analytic` this simple statement cleared a lot up for me. +1.

Answer (score 40):

It provides rolled-up data without rolling up

i.e. Suppose I want to return the relative position of sales region

Using PARTITION BY, I can return the sales amount for a given region **and** the MAX amount across all sales regions in the same row.

This does mean you will have repeating data, but it may suit the end consumer in the sense that data has been aggregated but no data has been lost - as would be the case with GROUP BY.

Answer (score 25):

As of my understanding Partition By is almost identical to Group By, but with the following differences:

That group by actually groups the result set returning one row per group, which results therefore in SQL Server only allowing in the SELECT list aggregate functions or columns that are part of the group by clause (in which case SQL Server can guarantee that there are unique results for each group).

Consider for example MySQL which allows to have in the SELECT list columns that are not defined in the Group By clause, in which case one row is still being returned per group, however if the column doesn't have unique results then there is no guarantee what will be the output!

But with Partition By, although the results of the function are identical to the results of an aggregate function with Group By, still you are getting the normal result set, which means that one is getting one row per underlying row, and not one row per group, and because of this one can have columns that are not unique per group in the SELECT list.

So as a summary, Group By would be best when needs an output of one row per group, and Partition By would be best when one needs all the rows but still wants the aggregate function based on a group.

Of course there might also be performance issues, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ms-MY/transactsql/thread/0b20c2b5-1607-40bc-b7a7-0c60a2a55fba.

Answer (score 9):

#### `PARTITION BY` semantics

Your question was specifically about SQL Server, which currently only supports a `PARTITION BY` clause only in window functions, but as I've explained in this blog post about [the various meanings of `PARTITION BY` in SQL](https://blog.jooq.org/various-meanings-of-sqls-partition-by-syntax/), there are also others, including:

- Window partitions (window functions are a SQL standard)
- Table partitions (vendor specific extensions to organise storage, e.g. in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/vldbg/) or [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html))
- `MATCH_REGOGNIZE` partitions (which is also a SQL standard)
- `MODEL` or `SPREADSHEET` partitions (an Oracle extension to SQL)
- `OUTER JOIN` partitions (a SQL standard)

Apart from the last one, which re-uses the `PARTITION BY` syntax to implement some sort of `CROSS JOIN` logic, all of these `PARTITION BY` clauses have the same meaning:

> A partition separates a data set into subsets, which don’t overlap.

Based on this partitioning, further calculations or storage operations *per partition* can be implemented. E.g. with window functions, such as `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY criteria)`, the `COUNT(*)` value is calculated *per partition*.

#### `GROUP BY` semantics

`GROUP BY` allows for similar partitioning behaviour, although it also [transforms the semantics of your entire query in various weird ways](https://blog.jooq.org/do-you-really-understand-sqls-group-by-and-having-clauses/). Most queries using `GROUP BY` can be rewritten using window functions, instead, although often, the `GROUP BY` syntax is more concise and possibly also better optimised.

For example, these are the logically the same, but I would expect the `GROUP BY` clause to perform better:

```sql
-- Classic
SELECT a, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY a

-- Using window functions
SELECT DISTINCT a, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a)
FROM t
```

The key difference is:

- Window functions can also be non-aggregate functions, e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()`
- Each window function can have its own `PARTITION BY` clause, whereas `GROUP BY` can only group by one set of expressions per query.

Comment: To extend this comprehensive list, PARTITION BY could also be found as a way to divide workload for Table Functions, here example from Snowflake: [Table Functions and Partitions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/java/udf-java-tabular-functions.html#table-functions-and-partitions)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Thanks for the pointer, nice to know. That's... weird. I mean, any partitioning or ordering can easily be undone by hash joins, hash grouping, or other operators that happen after the table function access. I guess I would have expected some hint syntax instead, for this kind of non-logic influencing optimisation functionality.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `GROUP BY`, the resulting rows will be usually less then incoming rows.

But, when you use `PARTITION BY`, the resulting row count should be the same as incoming.

Comment: does incoming mean uncommited rows here ?

Answer (score 1):

Small observation. Automation mechanism to dynamically generate SQL using the 'partition by' it is much simpler to implement in relation to the 'group by'. In the case of 'group by', We must take care of the content of 'select' column.

Sorry for My English.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have 14 records of `name` column in table

in `group by`

```
select name,count(*) as totalcount from person where name='Please fill out' group BY name;
```

it will give count in single row i.e 14

but in `partition by`

```
select row_number() over (partition by name) as total from person where name = 'Please fill out';
```

it will 14 rows of increase in count

Answer (score 0):

It has really different usage scenarios.
When you use GROUP BY you merge some of the records for the columns that are same and you have an aggregation of the result set.

However when you use PARTITION BY your result set is same but you just have an aggregation over the window functions and you don't merge the records, you will still have the same count of records.

Here is a rally helpful article explaining the difference:
http://alevryustemov.com/sql/sql-partition-by/

Answer (score -1):

```
-- BELOW IS A SAMPLE WHICH OUTLINES THE SIMPLE DIFFERENCES
-- READ IT AND THEN EXECUTE IT
-- THERE ARE THREE ROWS OF EACH COLOR INSERTED INTO THE TABLE
-- CREATE A database called testDB


-- use testDB
USE [TestDB]
GO


-- create Paints table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Paints](
    [Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [glossLevel] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


-- Populate Table
insert into paints (color, glossLevel)
select 'red', 'eggshell'
union
select 'red', 'glossy'
union
select 'red', 'flat'
union
select 'blue', 'eggshell'
union
select 'blue', 'glossy'
union
select 'blue', 'flat'
union
select 'orange', 'glossy'
union
select 'orange', 'flat'
union
select 'orange', 'eggshell'
union
select 'green', 'eggshell'
union
select 'green', 'glossy'
union
select 'green', 'flat'
union
select 'black', 'eggshell'
union
select 'black', 'glossy'
union
select 'black', 'flat'
union
select 'purple', 'eggshell'
union
select 'purple', 'glossy'
union
select 'purple', 'flat'
union
select 'salmon', 'eggshell'
union
select 'salmon', 'glossy'
union
select 'salmon', 'flat'


/*   COMPARE 'GROUP BY' color to 'OVER (PARTITION BY Color)'  */

-- GROUP BY Color 
-- row quantity defined by group by
-- aggregate (count(*)) defined by group by
select count(*) from paints
group by color

-- OVER (PARTITION BY... Color 
-- row quantity defined by main query
-- aggregate defined by OVER-PARTITION BY
select color
, glossLevel
, count(*) OVER (Partition by color)
from paints

/* COMPARE 'GROUP BY' color, glossLevel to 'OVER (PARTITION BY Color, GlossLevel)'  */

-- GROUP BY Color, GlossLevel
-- row quantity defined by GROUP BY
-- aggregate (count(*)) defined by GROUP BY
select count(*) from paints
group by color, glossLevel



-- Partition by Color, GlossLevel
-- row quantity defined by main query
-- aggregate (count(*)) defined by OVER-PARTITION BY
select color
, glossLevel
, count(*) OVER (Partition by color, glossLevel)
from paints
```