# Fetching values from a table without using CURSORS

Tags: sql-server, cursor

My table has the following structure

```
ID  MName  FName
1   Sunil Sachin
2   Sunil Sanjay
3   Sunil Wasim
4   Greg  Ricky
5   Ian   Mark
```

I want the query to return

```
1 Sunil Sachin, Sanjay, Wasim
2 Sunil Sachin, Sanjay, Wasim
3 Sunil Sachin, Sanjay, Wasim
4 Greg Ricky
5 Ian Mark
```

Comment: Why do you need a cursor in the first place?

Comment: Why repeat the first row thrice?

Comment: The data is already in production. Need to generate a report in SQL Server. I know how to get it using a CURSOR and COALESCE. But it is costly. Is there an elegant way to do the same?

Comment: what exactly is your query doing? i mean what is the logic here? can you post your solution using CURSOR

Comment: select Data.ID, Data.MName, Names.FNames
from Data
    join 
    (
        select MName, left(names, len(names) - 1) as FNames
        from Data as extern
            cross apply (select FName + ', '
                         from Data as intern
                         where extern.MName = intern.MName
                         for xml path('')
                        ) pre_trimmed (names)
        group by MName, names
    ) Names ON Data.MName = Names.MName
order by Data.ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this method](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) to do a 'group_concat' and get the results you want:

```
with Data(ID, MName, FName) as
(
    select 1, 'Sunil', 'Sachin'
    union
    select 2, 'Sunil', 'Sanjay'
    union
    select 3, 'Sunil', 'Wasim'
    union
    select 4, 'Greg', 'Ricky'
    union
    select 5, 'Ian', 'Mark'
)
select Data.ID, Data.MName, Names.FNames
from Data
    join 
    (
        select MName, left(names, len(names) - 1) as FNames
        from Data as extern
            cross apply (select FName + ', '
                         from Data as intern
                         where extern.MName = intern.MName
                         for xml path('')
                        ) pre_trimmed (names)
        group by MName, names
    ) Names ON Data.MName = Names.MName
order by Data.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Also http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/ is a very good link.

Comment: Hi,I have a question. What does pre_trimmed (names) do. I used any other string and it works too.

Comment: @Priyaranjan, `pre-trimmed` specifies the table alias to use for the derived table, and `(names)` is the column alias.  Since `pre-trimmed` isn't used anywhere in the query, you can change it whatever you'd like (`t`, `foo`, etc.).  You can also change the column alias, but you'll have to update the rest of the query if you do.

Comment: Yeah, understood it on second thought. Thanks a lot.