# Select a Column in SQL not in Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have been trying to find some info on how to select a non-aggregate column that is not contained in the Group By statement in SQL, but nothing I've found so far seems to answer my question. I have a table with three columns that I want from it. One is a create date, one is a ID that groups the records by a particular Claim ID, and the final is the PK. I want to find the record that has the max creation date in each group of claim IDs. I am selecting the MAX(creation date), and Claim ID (cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid), and grouping by the Claim ID. But I need the PK from these records (cpe.fmgcms_claimid), and if I try to add it to my select clause, I get an error. And I can't add it to my group by clause because then it will throw off my intended grouping. Does anyone know any workarounds for this? Here is a sample of my code:

```
Select MAX(cpe.createdon) As MaxDate, cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid 
from Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate cpe
where cpe.createdon < 'reportstartdate'
group by cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid
```

This is the result I'd like to get:

```
Select MAX(cpe.createdon) As MaxDate, cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid, cpe.fmgcms_claimid 
from Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate cpe
where cpe.createdon < 'reportstartdate'
group by cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid
```

Answer (score 60):

The columns in the result set of a `select` query with `group by` clause must be:

- an expression used as one of the `group by` criteria , or ...
- an aggregate function , or ...
- a literal value

So, you can't do what you want to do in a single, simple query. The first thing to do is state your problem statement in a clear way, something like:

> I want to find the individual claim row bearing the most recent
>   creation date within each group in my claims table

Given

```
create table dbo.some_claims_table
(
  claim_id     int      not null ,
  group_id     int      not null ,
  date_created datetime not null ,

  constraint some_table_PK primary key ( claim_id                ) ,
  constraint some_table_AK01 unique    ( group_id , claim_id     ) ,
  constraint some_Table_AK02 unique    ( group_id , date_created ) ,

)
```

The first thing to do is identify the most recent creation date for each group:

```
select group_id ,
       date_created = max( date_created )
from dbo.claims_table
group by group_id
```

That gives you the selection criteria you need (1 row per group, with 2 columns: group_id and the highwater created date) to fullfill the 1st part of the requirement (selecting the individual row from each group. That needs to be a virtual table in your final `select` query:

```
select *
from dbo.claims_table t
join ( select group_id ,
       date_created = max( date_created )
       from dbo.claims_table
       group by group_id
      ) x on x.group_id     = t.group_id
         and x.date_created = t.date_created
```

If the table is not unique by `date_created` within `group_id` (AK02), you you can get duplicate rows for a given group.

Comment: Without duplicate rows but with a correlated subquery `select  claim_id, group_id, date_created from some_claims_table as c1 where exists(select 1 from some_claims_table group by group_id having max(date_created) = c1.date_created);`

Answer (score 30):

You can do this with `PARTITION` and `RANK`:

```
select * from
(
    select MyPK, fmgcms_cpeclaimid, createdon,  
        Rank() over (Partition BY fmgcms_cpeclaimid order by createdon DESC) as Rank
    from Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate 
    where createdon < 'reportstartdate' 
) tmp
where Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 11):

The direct answer is that you can't.  You ***must*** select either an aggregate or something that you are grouping by.

So, you need an alternative approach.

1). Take you current query and join the base data back on it

```
SELECT
  cpe.*
FROM
  Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate cpe
INNER JOIN
  (yourQuery) AS lookup
    ON  lookup.MaxData           = cpe.createdOn
    AND lookup.fmgcms_cpeclaimid = cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid
```

2). Use a CTE to do it all in one go...

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY fmgcms_cpeclaimid ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC) AS sequence_id
  FROM
    Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate
  WHERE
    createdon < 'reportstartdate'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

NOTE: Using `ROW_NUMBER()` will ensure just one record per `fmgcms_cpeclaimid`.  Even if multiple records are tied with the exact same `createdon` value.  If you can have ties, and want all records with the same `createdon` value, use `RANK()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can `join` the table on itself to get the PK:

```
Select cpe1.PK, cpe2.MaxDate, cpe1.fmgcms_cpeclaimid 
from Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate cpe1
INNER JOIN
(
    select MAX(createdon) As MaxDate, fmgcms_cpeclaimid 
    from Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate
    group by fmgcms_cpeclaimid
) cpe2
    on cpe1.fmgcms_cpeclaimid = cpe2.fmgcms_cpeclaimid
    and cpe1.createdon = cpe2.MaxDate
where cpe1.createdon < 'reportstartdate'
```

Comment: Of all the variations of "select what isn't grouped", this one appeals to me the most.  Clean and gets to what you need, especially for simple summaries on a single join.

Answer (score 6):

Thing I like to do is to wrap addition columns in aggregate function, like `max()`. 
It works very good when you don't expect duplicate values.

```
Select MAX(cpe.createdon) As MaxDate, cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid, MAX(cpe.fmgcms_claimid) As fmgcms_claimid 
from Filteredfmgcms_claimpaymentestimate cpe
where cpe.createdon < 'reportstartdate'
group by cpe.fmgcms_cpeclaimid
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking, Sir, is as the answer of RedFilter.
This answer as well helps in understanding why group by is somehow a simpler version or partition over:
    [SQL Server: Difference between PARTITION BY and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404565/sql-server-difference-between-partition-by-and-group-by)
since it changes the way the returned value is calculated and therefore you could (somehow) return columns group by can not return.

Answer (score -1):

You can use as below,

```
Select X.a, X.b, Y.c from (
                Select X.a as a, sum (b) as sum_b from name_table X
                group by X.a)X
left join from name_table Y on Y.a = X.a
```

Example;

```
CREATE TABLE #products (
    product_name VARCHAR(MAX),
    code varchar(3),
    list_price [numeric](8, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #products VALUES ('paku', 'ACE', 2000)
INSERT INTO #products VALUES ('paku', 'ACE', 2000)
INSERT INTO #products VALUES ('Dinding', 'ADE', 2000)
INSERT INTO #products VALUES ('Kaca', 'AKB', 2000)
INSERT INTO #products VALUES ('paku', 'ACE', 2000)

--SELECT * FROM #products 
SELECT distinct x.code, x.SUM_PRICE, product_name FROM (SELECT code, SUM(list_price) as SUM_PRICE From #products 
               group by code)x
left join #products y on y.code=x.code

DROP TABLE #products
```