# Bigquery: Select a column with any value not in group by clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

It is a classical question and I know there are many work around like here: [Select a Column in SQL not in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991079/select-a-column-in-sql-not-in-group-by) but they do not work for my issue on Bigquery.

I have a table with tweets from Twitter and I want a ranking for the urls including any tweet text.

```
ID         tweet               url
1          my github tweet     http://www.github.com/xyz
2          RT github tweet     http://www.github.com/xyz
3          another tweet       http://www.twitter.com
4          more tweeting       http://www.github.com/abc
```

I tried the following query, but then id 1 and 2 are counted separately.

```
SELECT tweet, count(url) as popularity, url FROM table group by tweet, url order by popularity desc
```

How can I count/rank the urls correctly and still preserve any associated tweet text in the result? I do not care if it is from ID 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT url, COUNT(*) AS popularity, GROUP_CONCAT(tweet) 
FROM Table GROUP BY url ORDER BY popularity
```

GROUP_CONCAT aggregation function will concatenate all the tweets associated with same URL using comma as separator (you can pick another separator as second parameter to GROUP_CONCAT).

Comment: Works perfect. I added a left() to truncate the output and I am happy with that.

Comment: @crisscross in case you only want one tweet, you could also do SELECT url, COUNT(*) AS popularity, MAX(tweet) 
FROM Table GROUP BY url ORDER BY popularity (GROUP_CONCAT will struggle if there are too many tweets to group by)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work with *google-bigquery* or not, I haven't experience with it but this is a solution with pure sql I thought it may works for you.

get the `count` of `url`s in a subquery and then `join` it with the table on `url`:

```
select t.id,t.tweet,t.url,q.popularity
from table t
join 
(SELECT url, count(url) as popularity
FROM table group by url) q
on t.url=q.url
order by q.popularity desc
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. It did not completely worked out like that, but I am glad to see there is an option with a join statement.