# C# Query Builder SQL statement not working. How do I fix it?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, query-builder

I'm trying to GROUP BY in a SQL statement using Query Builder in VS 2015, but it's not working... Can you please tell me what's wrong?  Thank you!  :)

```
SELECT students_details.class AS Class, students.name AS Name, students.guardian AS Gurdian, students.phone AS Phone, students.mobile AS Mobile
FROM students_det INNER JOIN students ON students_details.studentID = students.studentID
ORDER BY Class
GROUP BY Class
```

Comment: If you're using `GROUP BY`, you may only select the columns you're grouping by or aggregation functions. More info in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991079/select-a-column-in-sql-not-in-group-by).

Comment: @smoksnes Please convert your comment to answer.

Comment: @codelab - Sure. It barely counts as an answer, but now it's there...

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), you may only select the columns you're grouping by or [aggregation functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp). More info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991079/select-a-column-in-sql-not-in-group-by). Or as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) puts it:

> A SELECT statement clause that divides the query result into groups of
>   rows, usually for the purpose of performing one or more aggregations
>   on each group. The SELECT statement returns one row per group.

So in your case you can only select `Class`, because each row will be grouped by `Class`. You can look at it as a `Dictionary<string, List<Row>>` in C# where the `string` here is the different classes and the `Row` is the rest of the rows. Or like a two dimensional array.

What you probably want to do is to simply order by class (without `group by`), or do an aggregation function on class. Such as, how many students are there in each class?

```
SELECT students_details.class AS Class, count(*) AS NumberOfStudents
FROM students_det INNER JOIN students ON students_details.studentID = students.studentID
ORDER BY Class
GROUP BY Class
```