# How to use Oracle JOIN with GROUP BY effectively so that I can select multiple columns from both tables and applying Aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have Database Schema as -

```
create table Manufacturer (mid integer primary key, name varchar(20), address varchar(56));

create table Supplies(sid integer references Supplier(sid), pid integer references Product(pid));
```

I have a problem which states-

> **List the ids and names of manufacturers and the count of products manufactured by each**

So, I tried GROUP BY with JOIN but it is failing when I try to show `mid,name,count(pid)` together by showing `not a GROUP BY expression error`.

But I have successfully executed the following->

```
select name,count(m2.pid) from Manufacturer m1 inner join Manufactures m2 on m1.mid=m2.mid group by name;
```

which gives me the names and corresponding Number of products successfully.
**But when I try to add mid column to show `mid` along with the other two-`name` and `count(pid)` it shows error -**

```
select m1.mid,name,count(m2.pid) from Manufacturer m1 inner join Manufactures m2 on m1.mid=m2.mid group by name;
```

Just adding the `m1.mid` forces an error!

**It also gives error when I try to GROUP BY `mid` - the joining criteria!**

```
select m1.mid,name,count(m2.pid) from Manufacturer m1 inner join Manufactures m2 on m1.mid=m2.mid group by m1.mid;
```

Is it because `mid` is the joining criteria for the 2 tables ?and so I cannot use that in the GROUP BY  section? 
I am unsure what is the error or what concept I am missing!
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're using `group by` incorrectly, don't over-analyze. Edit your question and add sample data and expected output in text format. We'll try to provide you with a working query.

Comment: There is no single mid per group, how can you ask for it? Read what group by & aggregates do & what the problem is for that error message. Don't write sentences with '!' that contradict what you were just told, give your misconceived justification for your '!' sentence. PS This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a Column in SQL not in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991079/select-a-column-in-sql-not-in-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matters:

```
select 
  count(m2.pid),  --> aggregation
  m1.mid, name    --> columns that aren't aggregated MUST be in the GROUP BY clause
from ...
group by m1.mid, name
```

---

Also, I'd suggest to use table aliases always, everywhere (the `name` column doesn't have it).