# Using "GROUP BY" while joining two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, group-by, count

I've run into an issue I can't seem to figure out and haven't found any solution out on the web.

I have two tables; One with Authors and one with books. I need to summarize the information but I can't get the `group by` condition to work or `count` for that matter, but I think that's caused by my problems with `group by`.

My code is:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS [Name],
    CASE WHEN a.DeathDate IS NULL
        THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,a.BirthDate,SYSUTCDATETIME())
        ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR,a.BirthDate,a.DeathDate)
    END AS [Age]
    ,COUNT(a.ID) AS [Books]
    
FROM Author a LEFT JOIN Books b ON a.ID = b.AuthorID 

group by a.ID
```

If I remove the `count` and `group by` I get a table where the names of the authors repeat, because some have written several book, which is to be expected. What I'm trying to do is count the number of books they have written, add that as a column and remove the name repetition.

Table without `group by` & `count`:

```
|      ROW    |     ID     |     Name   |     Age    |
|-------------|------------|------------|------------|
|      1      |     1      |    Adam    |     50     |
|      2      |     1      |    Adam    |     50     |
|      3      |     2      |    Sven    |     36     |
|      4      |     2      |    Sven    |     36     |
|      5      |     3      |    Eric    |     82     |
|      6      |     4      |    Rick    |     75     |
```

Table I wish i had:

```
|      ROW    |     ID     |     Name   |     Age    |     Books  |
|-------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|      1      |     1      |    Adam    |     50     |     2      |
|      2      |     2      |    Sven    |     36     |     2      |
|      3      |     3      |    Eric    |     82     |     1      |
|      4      |     4      |    Rick    |     75     |     1      |
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` *all* the columns you aren't aggregating. You only have `a.ID` in your `GROUP BY`, but you have 4 other columns you aren't aggregating.

Comment: Skip the JOIN and GROUP BY. Have a correlated subquery to count each author's number of books.

Comment: Duplicate of [Select a Column in SQL not in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11991079/3404097)

Comment: @Larnu, I think I might be stupid or my teacher is not very good, not sure which. I for some reason thought that ```GROUP BY```  just grouped up the lines if they had the same value in the mentioned column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlated subquery sounds good:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS [Name],
    CASE WHEN a.DeathDate IS NULL
        THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,a.BirthDate,SYSUTCDATETIME())
        ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR,a.BirthDate,a.DeathDate)
    END AS [Age]
    ,q1.books_count AS [Books]
    
FROM 
    Author a 
    outer apply(
        select count(*) as books_count
        from Books b 
        where a.ID = b.AuthorID 
    ) as q1
```

Comment: Cool thanks man, never seen "outer apply" before, guess I'll read up on that.