# Top 5 Sales people with their total sales

Tags: sql, join, group-by, subquery

I'm trying to find the top 5 sales people based on their total sales. I want to show the rep's names, and their total sales, and I'm working in AdventureWorks.

The thing that keeps throwing me off is the `GROUP BY` statement. In the query below, I'm not sure why the `GROUP BY` isn't working. I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but at this point I'm just trying to really learn joins and subqueries, and the way in which `GROUP BY` works seems to be something I'm not grasping.

```
SELECT SalesLT.Customer.SalesPerson, SUM(repjoin.TotalDue) OVER (PARTITION BY repjoin.salesperson)
FROM SalesLT.customer INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID, 
            SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader.TotalDue, 
            SalesLT.Customer.SalesPerson
    FROM SalesLT.Customer
        INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader
        ON SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID = SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID
    ) repjoin
        ON SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID = repjoin.CustomerID
GROUP BY SalesLT.Customer.SalesPerson
```

Comment: what's the actual issue? Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404565/sql-server-difference-between-partition-by-and-group-by

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When posting questions, when possible, please remember to show your expected results and and the results you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
SELECT TOP 5
  c.SalesPerson, 
  SUM(soh.TotalDue) TotalSales
FROM
  SalesLT.Customer c
  INNER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader soh ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
  c.SalesPerson
ORDER BY
  SUM(soh.TotalDue) DESC
```

?

Comment: This should be the answer you want.  To explain, `GROUP BY` simply collapses the results based on the specified values.  Grouping by `c.SalesPerson` collapses the results to one row per salesperson allowing you to use aggregate functions (such as `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc) on the non-grouped columns in the results.  Note, only the columns you grouped by can be be referred to without aggregate functions.