# How do I count the number of Values inserted in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table like below:

```
DirectoryName    FileName
    A               Ab.pdf
    B               bc.mp3
    C               cd.doc
    A               de.pdf
    F               fg.pdf
    A               kl.pdf
```

The output should be like this:

```
Directory 
 A - 3
 B - 1
 C - 1
 F - 1
```

And same with FileName.

Thanks

Comment: Use a `.GroupBy` query

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution is :

```
select distinct DirectoryName, count(FileName) 
from tableName group by DirectoryName
```

Or you can use **partition by** over ***DirectoryName***

```
select distinct DirectoryName, COUNT(FileName) 
over(Partition by DirectoryName) 
Count from tableName
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I was not knowing your requirement, so given both the solutions, if you want to know the difference between this two read this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2404587/7614961

Comment: close the question once you are satisfied with answer. @Sam