# Range based window Frame can have only 1 sort key

Tags: sql, hive, analytic-functions

Ive tried to run the next query

```
select sum(balance) over (partition by client order by card desc, date_tr desc)
from table_1
```

And in Result i have the next error message:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Range based Window Frame can have only 1 Sort key
```

Is it true, that i cant use 2 sort keys in `order by` sentence? Or there is a way how can i use 2 sort keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should work.  The [language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-PARTITIONBYwithtwopartitioningcolumns,twoORDERBYcolumns,andnowindowspecification) has a very similar example.

That said, an explicit window clause might get around the error:

```
select sum(balance) over (partition by client
                          order by card desc, date_tr desc
                          rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         )
from table_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this answer to understand the difference between GROUP and PARTITION BY, it should work though it depends what exactly you want: [Difference GROUP BY and PARTITION BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404565/sql-server-difference-between-partition-by-and-group-by)