GroupBy in MirkoORM
I have an Entity that looks like this:
@Entity({ tableName: 'certificates' })
export class CertificateEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Property({ type: 'float' })
  version: number;

  @Property()
  name: string;

  @Property()
  type: CertificateType;

  @Property()
  description: string;
}

I am trying to get a list of the latest certificates by version for every type. So only the highest version of each type should appear.
I am running
const r = await this.em.createQueryBuilder(CertificateEntity)
      .select(['type', 'version'])
      .groupBy('type')
      .execute();

But what I am getting is
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "path": "/certificates/list",
    "errorType": "error",
    "errorMessage": "select \"c0\".\"type\", \"c0\".\"version\" from \"certificates\" as \"c0\" group by \"c0\".\"type\" - column \"c0.version\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"
}

If I add the version as instructed by the error message. I just get the list
[
    {
        "version": 1.7,
        "type": "s-type"
    },
    {
        "version": 1.6,
        "type": "s-type"
    },
    {
        "version": 1.5,
        "type": "s-type"
    }
]

What am I doing wrong?

The error says "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function", and for what you want to do, the second part is valid, not the first one. You want to use an aggregate function for the columns you want to select but not group by them. This is because the grouping can produce different values for the version - and based on what you say you want, you should be selecting max(version) and not just version.
Try this instead:
const r = await this.em.createQueryBuilder(CertificateEntity)
      .select(['type', sql`max(version)`])
      .groupBy('type')
      .execute();

sql is a helper exported from he @mikro-orm/core or any other driver package, see https://mikro-orm.io/docs/raw-queries

That looks encouraging, and it returns the list I want, but when I add another field
in the select, like 'id' for example, I get an error select "c0"."type", max(version) as version, "c0"."id" from "certificates" as "c0" group by "c0"."type" - column "c0.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

yes, the very same error, for the very same reason. you need to use aggregate function on anything you want to select and is not part of the group by clause.

Apologies, do you mean it can be done? Can you please edit the response to include other fields like name?

well, but which ones? you group several values because of the group by clause, its up to you to explicitly tell the engine which ones to pick, otherwise you get this error. it sounds like group by is not really what you want to do, a window function would be better, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71333740/3665878

unfortunately there is no native support for that in the ORM, you'd have to fall back to using knex or a raw query https://mikro-orm.io/docs/query-builder#mapping-raw-results-to-entities
